# convert alphanumeric value to date

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, datetime

I get `a1523245800` value in the date field from my incoming data feed. I wish to know, how to convert this value into the date dtype? I have tried `pandas.to_datetime` but that does not seem to work. thankyou.

here is my code

```
pd.to_datetime([`a1523245800`], errors='coerce')
```

and here is the output of the above:

```
DatetimeIndex(['NaT'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

Comment: Where's your code? what you tried? nothing is there? post with your code clearly,edit and avoid downvotes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `a` by `str[1:]` for remove first char or [`str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) for get numeric part first and then [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) with parameter `unit`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':['a1523245800','a1523245800']})

df['date1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'].str[1:], unit='s')
```

Or:

```
df['date1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'].str.extract('(\d+)', expand=False), unit='s')
print (df)

          date               date1
0  a1523245800 2018-04-09 03:50:00
1  a1523245800 2018-04-09 03:50:00
```

Comment: works, great. I was meddling with pd.to_datetime, but was unware of the kwargs 'unit='s''!